# idleTimerDisabled not working under iOS8 Gold Master

Tags: ios8, idle-timer

We have a video recording app which has worked fine under iOS6 and 7 and we thought it was working fine under the beta versions of iOS8. Since we have the Gold Master we are often pushed to the background when the iOS idle timer kicks in. We have the line:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

in our code and this has been sufficient until now. Does anyone know why this is not working all of a sudden.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you show a keyboard and dismiss keyboard after setIdieTimerDisabled, the idleTimerDisabled will not work automatically on iOS 8.

I don't know why, but these code could fix my problem:

```
- (void)onKeyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (!SystemVersionLessThan(@"8.0")) {
        //reset it again.
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    }
}
```